# ECMA6 Spread with a function in the middle vs forEach?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code block that works fine, but I feel like there is an ECMA6 simplification that I'm missing.

Concept code:

```
//set.data is an array of objects
service.find().then(set => {
    set.data.forEach(function(part, index) {
        set.data[index] = itemModificationFunction(set.data[index]);
    });
    this.items.push(...set.data);
});

var itemModificationFunction = function (data) {
    data.addFoo = 'additionalFoo';
    return data;
};
```

...vs. something like this...

```
service.find().then(set => {
    this.items.push(itemModificationFunction(...set.data));
});
```

...which of course doesn't work, as it only pushes the first array element.  Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: `const newData = set.data.map(item => itemModificationFunction(item)); this.items.push(...newData);` ?

Comment: Thank you!  And this works too, if you really wanted to:

`this.items.push(...set.data.map(item => itemModificationFunction(item)));`

Comment: if you really wanted to make an unreadable monster - yes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using yours. :)

Comment: `item => itemModificationFunction(item)` is the same as just `itemModificationFunction`, so you can just say `set.data.map(itemModficationFunction)`. Naming your functions this way is a bit verbose; why not just `modifyItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```
service.find().then(set => this.items.push(...set.data.map(modifyItem)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprised I haven't seen this but neither the spread or forEach are necessary. This is the most direct code, and is much faster for large arrays.

```
service.find().then(set => {
    this.items = this.items.concat(set.data.map(itemModificationFunction))
});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat` does not modify the source array in-place

Comment: And now the question: why should OP prefer your code over the other suggested?

Comment: pushing a spread of 10k elements is 92% slower in my browser :) https://jsperf.com/spread-push-v-concat

Comment: For 100k elements. Are you serious now?

Comment: 99% slower for 10k. Yes, serious(ly drunk). Still though, don't spread-push. https://jsperf.com/spread-push-v-concat-2